# Which C# data structure is best/feasible to store hierarchical data

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have below data structure:

[image]

Which C# data structure is best to store and retrieve these easily?

I want to be able to refer to Dev, Dev.Value1, Dev.Key1, Test, Test.Key1, so on..

Update: I have a json file and as I parse it I get these values. So the number of environments (Dev, Test) will be more like ( Dev, Test, UAT, Stable, Prod). Also the number of Key, Value pairs will be different in each environment. I need to store them separately in a structure to consume them later. As I parse the json I will get an environment (Dev) and all its key, values pairs and then I will get Test followed by all its key, value pairs.

Comment: Do you want a variable name for this also?

Comment: i want to store this structure in a data structure and to refer it i would need a variable i guess..

Comment: May be array of dictionary?

Comment: You could make a new class that holds a name "Dev", "Test", etc. and it could also hold a dictionary items (Value1 : Key1)

Comment: I believe that @Nikhil Agrawal was being sarcastic, but I would say an array of dictionaries, or just create a class, and make a collection/list of those.

Comment: i don't have these data in hand.. as i parse a json file i get these data.. so accordingly i need a way.. i guess i will go ahead with an array of dictionaries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make class like this...

```
public class Environment
{
    Dictionary<string, string> KeyValueData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Environment(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        KeyValueData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void AddNewData(string key, string value)
    {
        this.KeyValueData.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Environment> environments = new List<Environment>();
Environment env = new Environment("Test");
env.AddNewData("key1", "value1");
env.AddNewData("key2", "value2");
env.AddNewData("key3", "value3");

Environment env2 = new Environment("Prod");
env2.AddNewData("key1", "value1");
env2.AddNewData("key2", "value2");
env2.AddNewData("key3", "value3");
//...
environments.Add(env2);
```

Comment: Dear Nino i guess i did not give full scenario.. My scenario is that I have these data in a json file already.. and as I parse it i need to store these data.. so I don't have the data in hand already.. during the parsing of the json i get the data..

Comment: @BaskarLingamRamachandran in that case, here's another approach. I have edited my answer, take a look

Comment: Much appreciate your honest answers and precious time.. I am taking a look.. will let you know.. Thanks again very much..

Comment: Perfect.. Just what I needed..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the work for you.

```
var environments = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "Dev", new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Key1", "Value1"},
            {"Key2", "Value2"}
        }
    },
    {
        "Test", new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Key1", "Value1"},
            {"Key2", "Value2"}
        }
    }
};

var devKey1 = environments["Dev"]["Key1"];

environments["Prod"] = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Key1", "Value1"},
    {"Key2", "Value2"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said, you could easily make your own class for this, but since you are asking this question I assume you need or would prefer to use existing code. What you need is a dictionary of dictionaries.

For example

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> ImAssBackwards = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
ImAssBackwards.Add("Dev", 
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {
                "Key1",
                "Value1"
            },
            {
                "Key2",
                "Value2"
            }
        });

Dictionary<string, string> PantOnHeadSilly = ImAssBackwards["Dev"];
```

Comment: @Eugene Great minds right :D? But I like you answer for giving more example usages.